# Issue when use a Control Layer on marker out of group on Drupal with custom module

Tags: leaflet, drupal-8, leaflet.markercluster

When a marker is out of a group (cyrcle numbered) if I use the control filters by clicking on a checkbox the marker disappears correctly, by clicking on the checkbox again it no longer appears. This does not happen with the markers present in the groups.

[image: Video Example]

Here the [project on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-6tzs1g?embed=1&file=script.js),this doesn't work on Drupal in my custom module.

Here the [Drupal site](http://diggingup.nanoalias.it).

---

Edit
I just found out that it doesn't just work when logged in. Everything seems to work anonymously.

Comment: Please could you share a live reproduction example, e.g. using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz?

Comment: I tried to reproducting it at StackBlitz and it actually works! -.-
The problem I have since then due to some internal Drupal mechanics that breaks javascript calls.